# When to use "in" versus "through"?

Tags: prepositions

When to use "in" versus "through"?

> **Through** my work experience as a Customer Service Specialist **for** T-Mobile, I honed my interpersonal skills.

> **In** my work experience as a Customer Service Specialist **for** T-Mobile, I honed my interpersonal skills.

Also, is the word "for" the correct preposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 'I learned [x] *in* [y]' would mean that [x] was a *specific* experience or learning point in [y]. For example, if you studied programming at college you would say you learned programming "in" college.
- 'I learned [x] *through* [y]' means that [y] was a *route* to your learning - that you perhaps learned [x] as a *consequence* of experiencing [y]. For example, you might say "I learned compassion through my work with disadvantaged people". The work wasn't actually a structured lesson in compassion, but it was something you learned along the way.

Your example works better with "through", because you learned something as a consequence of working. You were there to work, not learn specifically, but you learned via that work.